# Blazor SignalR app error AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: signalr, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

I am simply trying to implement the example from the following link i.e.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server
when I run the application I happen to get the following error.

[image: SignalR error]

I also tried the following after doing the google search but couldn't resolve it.

```
HubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"), configureHttpConnection =>
{
//configureHttpConnection.WebSocketConfiguration = (sockets) =>
//{
//    sockets.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => { return true; 
 });
 //};
 //configureHttpConnection.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (x) => new HttpClientHandler
 //{
 //    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
 //};
  })
   .Build();
```

Also I ensured that self signed certificate is available under Trusted Root Certification Authorities